# Why overprint-environment not fix position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I use `overprint` environment in beamer with two columns, when overlay it move down and the last slide has some space. How can I solve this problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\footnotesize\tt #1}
\newcommand{\codealert}[1]{\alert{\code{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
\code{\textbackslash begin\{tikzpicture\}}\\
\code{\textbackslash node[circle,draw](a) at (0,0)\{a\};}\\
\code{\textbackslash node[circle,draw](b) at (1,1)\{b\};}\\
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) -- (b);}}\\
\onslide<2>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) to (b);}}\\
\onslide<3>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) -| (b);}}\\
\onslide<4>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) |- (b);}}
\end{overprint}
\code{\textbackslash begin\{tikzpicture\}}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\tikz{
\draw (-1,-1) rectangle +(3,3);
\node [circle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node [circle, draw] (b) at (1,1) {b};
\onslide<1>{\draw [->,red] (a) -- (b);}
\onslide<2>{\draw [->,red] (a) to (b);}
\onslide<3>{\draw [->,red] (a) -| (b);}
\onslide<4>{\draw [->,red] (a) |- (b);}
}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code doesn't produce any jumps; I fixed a little typo at the end and moved the and removed `overprint` which was not really needed (at least not in this example):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily #1}
\newcommand{\codealert}[1]{\alert{\code{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
\code{\textbackslash begin\{tikzpicture\}}\\
\code{\textbackslash node[circle,draw](a) at (0,0)\{a\};}\\
\code{\textbackslash node[circle,draw](b) at (1,1)\{b\};}\\
\onslide<1>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) -- (b);}}\\
\onslide<2>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) to (b);}}\\
\onslide<3>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) -| (b);}}\\
\onslide<4>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) |- (b);}}
\code{\textbackslash end\{tikzpicture\}}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\tikz{
\draw (-1,-1) rectangle +(3,3);
\node [circle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node [circle, draw] (b) at (1,1) {b};
\onslide<1>{\draw [->,red] (a) -- (b);}
\onslide<2>{\draw [->,red] (a) to (b);}
\onslide<3>{\draw [->,red] (a) -| (b);}
\onslide<4>{\draw [->,red] (a) |- (b);}
}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have only one red lineper slide, use `\only` instead of `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily #1}
\newcommand{\codealert}[1]{\alert{\code{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.55\textwidth}
\code{\textbackslash begin\{tikzpicture\}}\\
\code{\textbackslash node[circle,draw](a) at (0,0)\{a\};}\\
\code{\textbackslash node[circle,draw](b) at (1,1)\{b\};}\\
\begin{overprint}
\only<1>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) -- (b);}\\}
\only<2>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) to (b);}\\}
\only<3>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) -| (b);}\\}
\only<4>{\codealert{\textbackslash draw[->](a) |- (b);}}
\code{\textbackslash end\{tikzpicture\}}
\end{overprint}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\tikz{
\draw (-1,-1) rectangle +(3,3);
\node [circle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node [circle, draw] (b) at (1,1) {b};
\onslide<1>{\draw [->,red] (a) -- (b);}
\onslide<2>{\draw [->,red] (a) to (b);}
\onslide<3>{\draw [->,red] (a) -| (b);}
\onslide<4>{\draw [->,red] (a) |- (b);}
}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The main probem : there are four lines (red lines) in output, I want only one.

Comment: @somkiat_t please see my updated answer (use \only instead of \onslide).